# ListView elements beside each other

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview

I would like create an application with a list of podcast with an UI like Google Music, but I do not know how to place items horizontally beside the other podcasts rather than below.

I use a listView and a cardView.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) or a [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with a [GridLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) can do the trick.

Comment: @xav-stargate  hi im trying you implement you php passbook  can you help me im having some path issues  `https://github.com/xav-stargate/webservice-passbook`